# Proving continuity of the following piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

Consider the following function : 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2-9 \ & \text{if}\ x \le 4 \\[2ex] 
\frac{2x^2-9x+4}{x-4} & \text{if}\ x >4 \end{cases}$$

Now I want to show that this function is continuous at $x =4$ using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. Seeing this at first I thought it might be easy to show but the calculation becomes messy and I can't find a proper $\delta$. I will show here some of my calculation,

Let $\epsilon >0$ now we need $\delta > 0$ so that $|x-4| <\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(4)| < \epsilon.$ We can form two cases for limit from both sides. First I check for $x \le4$.

We need $|f(x)-f(4)| < \epsilon \Rightarrow |x^2-16| <\epsilon \Rightarrow 16-\epsilon < x^2 < 16+\epsilon \Rightarrow x\in (-\sqrt{16+\epsilon}, -\sqrt{16-\epsilon}).$

Also, we need $|x-4| < \delta \Rightarrow 4-\delta < x < 4+\delta$. So how do I choose $\delta$ now?? I know how to do this but I can't figure here. I am getting confused. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: If $|x-4|<\delta$, then $|x^2-16|=|x-4|\cdot |x+4|<\delta(\delta +8)=\delta^2+8\delta$

Comment: Notice that for $x>4$ you have $f(x)=2x-1$, that should be easy.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Yeah that I know that.

Comment: @Fakemistake thanks, that helped. what I was doing wrong was to open the modulo and the square, which gave roots and I got confused, though I was able to see that $|x^2-16| = |x+4|\cdot |x-4|$, I didn't connect it to $\delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$ and assume that the $\delta$ that we are going to choose is less than $1$

Note that if $|x-4|<\delta$ and $\delta <1$ then we have $3<x<5$

Thus for $x< 4$,  $$|f(x)-7|=|x^2-9-7|=$$

$$|x^2-16|=|x+4||x-4|<9|x-4|<9\delta$$

On the other hand for $x\ge 4$,  $$ |f(x)-7|=|\frac {2x^2-5x+4}{x-4}-7|=$$

$$|2x-1-7|=|2x-8|=2|x-4|<2\delta$$
Thus if we choose $$\delta <\min \{\epsilon /9,1\} $$ then we have $$|f(x)-7|<\epsilon$$

Thus the function is continuous at $x=4$